# Process.StandardOutput.Readline() is hanging when there is no output

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, powershell-core

> **Note:** I am trying to run `packer.exe` as a background process to workaround a particular issue with the `azure-arm` builder, and I need to watch the output. I am not using
> `Start-Process` because I don't want to use an intermediary file to consume the output.

I have the following code setting up `packer.exe` to run in the background so I can consume its output and act upon a certain log message. This is part of a larger script but this is the bit in question that is not behaving correctly:

```
  $builderDir = ( Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath )
  Push-Location $builderDir
  
  # Set up the packer command to run asynchronously
  $pStartProps = @{
    FileName               = ( Get-Command -CommandType Application packer ).Source
    Arguments              = "build -var-file ""${builderDir}\win-dev.pkrvars.hcl"" -only ""azure-arm.base"" ."
    UseShellExecute        = $false
    RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    RedirectStandardError  = $false
    LoadUserProfile        = $true
  }
  $pStartInfo = New-Object ProcessStartInfo -Property $pStartProps

  $p = [Process]::Start($pStartInfo)

  while ( $null -ne ( $output = $p.StandardOutput.Readline() ) -or !$p.HasExited ) {
    # Do stuff
  }
```

Basically, the `( $output = $p.StandardOutput.Readline() )` portion of the `while` condition seems to be hanging until there is more output to be read. I'm not sure why this is, because `StreamReader.Readline()` [should either return the next line to be read, or `null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netcore-3.1#returns) if there is no more output. I have a fair bit of processing around this regarding the log message I'm expecting to get, so blocking when reading STDOUT when there is no further output to consume renders the script useless. There are other things it is doing in the foreground while `packer.exe` continues to execute.

I am able to confirm in the debugger that `Readline()` does read empty lines (value of `""`) fine, this seems to happen be when there is not yet further output to consume. This may be tangential but this causes the debugger to bug out as well.

When this issue occurs the VSCode debugger sits on this with
`$output = $p.StandardOutput.Readline()` highlighted for a few seconds, then the debugger stops (everything disappears, no more variable tracking, etc.) until `Readline()` stops blocking and execution continues, at which point the debugger seems to re-initialize the tracked variables, watched expressions, etc. So I can't use the debugger at all when this occurs. Even the
`PowerShell Integrated Console` (the one used with the debugger) hangs and I cannot type anything.

---

For full context, the goal of this script is to let `packer.exe` do its thing while I loop continuously to:

1. Display more output from `packer.exe`
2. Check for the presence of a certain log message
3. Give `packer.exe` a bit of time to try to do what it needs on its own
4. If it waits too long, I execute a script against the node being since what `packer.exe` should have done on its own likely failed

   - I am using `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` to do this, which can't be done at the state `packer.exe` for the issue I am working around. It must be performed out-of-band of the `packer.exe` run itself.
5. The build continues on after the workaround is applied and I simply continue forwarding the output of `packer.exe` to the console until the process exits

But since the script hangs when there is no output, step 4 will never work as I have to give packer time to try to complete the config on its own, and is the entire reason why I'm hacking this together in the first place.

---

Why is `Readline()` blocking here? Am I doing something incorrectly? This behavior occurs whether I run my script in Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core.

Comment: Haha, good to know. This script might end up running on a *nix builder in Azure so I'll keep that there might be cross-platform oddities to keep in mind around `StreamReader`, though reading from a file is something I'm trying to avoid so it might not be relevant to me. Goal for now is to get this building from the workstation though. This packer stuff has me ripping my hair out!

Comment: I think the use of a _file_ is incidental to my sample code - I just used it for convenience. I would expect the sample to work the same if you adapt it to your `Process` scenario (instead of `while ($true)`, use `while (-not $p.HasExited)`,  and so on - though you may want to ensure that all output has been received before exiting the loop.

Comment: Yeah I had to resort to a boolean flag for end of input since I banked on `null` meaning there was no new information to read. But if `null` means the output stream has been closed I should be able to assume the process is exited as well (though I still check for this at the end). In either case I'm trying what you suggested, may not be able to test until tomorrow morning though.

Comment: Maybe simply checking `$task.IsCompleted` _after_ the loop will do for finding a final line, if any.

Comment: It's not needed the way I implemented it. All done at the top of the loop, most of the code is logic for what to do after the line has been read. In any case it works great so thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine) is blocking by design.
- There is an *asynchronous* alternative, [`.ReadLineAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsync), which returns a [`Task<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) instance that you can *poll* for completion, via its `.IsCompleted` property, without blocking your foreground thread (polling is your only option in PowerShell, given that it has no language feature analogous to C#'s `await`).

Here's a simplified example that focuses on asynchronous reading from a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader) instance that happens to be a file, to which new lines are added only periodically; use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to abort.

I would expect the code to work the same if you adapt it to your stdout-reading [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) code.

```sh
# Create a sample input file.
$n=3
1..$n > tmp.txt

# Open the file for reading, and convert it to a System.IO.StreamReader instance.
[IO.StreamReader] $reader = 
  [IO.File]::Open("$pwd/tmp.txt", 'Open', 'Read', 'ReadWrite')

try {
  $task = $reader.ReadLineAsync() # Start waiting for the first line.
  while ($true) { # Loop indefinitely to wait for new lines.
    if ($task.IsCompleted) {  # A new line has been received.
      $task.Result # Output
      # Start waiting for the next line.
      $task.Dispose(); $task = $reader.ReadLineAsync(); 
    }
    else { # No new line available yet, do other things.
      Write-Host '.' -NoNewline
      Start-Sleep 1
    }
    # Append a new line to the sample file every once in a while.
    if (++$n % 10 -eq 0) { $n >> tmp.txt }
  }
}
finally {
  $reader.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `StreamReader` from standard output is waiting for IO - the stream from `StandardOutput` can't get opened for reading until it gets more data or the `Process` is closed. There's a similar issue with using `StreamReader` on TCP streams, where you get to enjoy waiting for network traffic.

The *usual* way around it is to let a different task wait on it via async reads like `ReadLineAsync()`. This doesn't help your `while` loop, because it still sits and waits the same amount before it can progress to read the output's `StreamReader`.

If `packer.exe`'s output behaves well, you can try using a powershell job's output property instead of `[process]`? I tested with `ping` that gives the same waiting-for-IO lockup behavior:

```
# Locks up for full ping timeout example: 
$pStartProps = @{ FileName  = 'ping.exe' ; Arguments = '10.bad.ip.0' ... }
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pStartInfo)

# Locks when reading
$output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
while ( $output -ne $null ) {
  $output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); ## read the output
  # Do stuff
}

#####

# Does not lock when using Job output instead:
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ping.exe 10.bad.ip.0 }

While ($job.State -ne 'Completed') {
  $job.ChildJobs[0].Output  ## read the output
  # Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is a good use of Start-Job but this script needs to process the output line by line as packer produces the output. Job.Output produces all of the output of the job at once, even after consuming it, no?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest You are correct, it outputs a single multiline string. You could diff `$output` with the previous loop to check for new data, for example. There may be better solutions though, depending on how you need to process the output.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I went the process.start route, but failed to recall that Readline() is in fact a blocking operation when waiting for output. It was something I had run into before back when I was a C# SE (seems like a lifetime ago now haha). `ReadlineAsync()` was easier to "drop in" based on the way I had already written my script.

Answer (score 3):

Using `StandardOutput.ReadLine()` as above, you set the Output redirection stream to use Synchronous read mode. This means that when you call `$p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` it behaves like a normal function call.

You call it, and wait for the return value. The return value is either a *complete line* or `$null` if the end of stream is reached. This means that as the running program fills the `System.Diagnostics.Process` output stream buffer with output, you continue to be a good synchronous PowerShell boy and wait for the function call to return. Once the `System.Diagnostics.Process` detects a newline in the stream, the function call `$p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` returns with your data, a ***full complete line***.

This is why it seems like it is blocking. It has to wait till it has a full line before the function can return.

The other return value, `$null`, makes more sense knowing that a `StreamReader` object is used for many different things that could have different endings for the stream. If you were using a `StreamReader` to read a text file, the end of the stream/file is when you hit the `EOF` marker. If you were reading in an array of characters, it could be the `\0` string terminator. `$null` in this case is a universal end of stream.

For a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object, it's definition of "the end of a stream" is when the process completes, not "I have no output at this moment".

In order to remove this blocking you have to perform your reading in an Asynchronous manner a.k.a. `ReadLineAsync()`.

Not wanting to step on @mklement0 toes, as he, correctly, solves your problem by using `ReadLineAsync()` to make it Asynchronous, and by polling to keep the checking/validation script inside the same scope. But an alternative method to read data asynchronously is to use [`Process.BeginOutputReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-5.0) and the [`OutputDataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-5.0) Event to Asynchronously fire off a Script Block when you have more data.

```
# Script to run when you have another line of data
$NewOutputSB = {
    param([object]$sender, [System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs]$e)
    Write-Host "  #  " $e.Data
}

$pStartProps = @{
    FileName               = ( Get-Command -CommandType Application ping.exe ).Source
    Arguments              = "8.8.8.8"
    UseShellExecute        = $false
    RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    RedirectStandardError  = $false
    LoadUserProfile        = $true
}
$pStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property $pStartProps

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

# Register the Event Handler
$EventSub = Register-ObjectEvent $p -EventName OutputDataReceived -Action $NewOutputSB

$p.StartInfo = $pStartInfo

$p.Start() | Out-Null

# Begin asynchronous reading on the Output stream
$p.BeginOutputReadLine()

# Do other work while we wait for it to finish running...
while ( !$p.HasExited ) {
    # Do stuff
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
    Write-Host "--- Do stuff"
}

# Cleanup Event Handler
Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $EventSub.Id
```

After running this code, the Output shows the stream running in Asynchronous mode:

```
PS C:\>
  #   
  #   Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
  #   Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=119
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
  #   Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=119
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
  #   Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=119
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
--- Do stuff
  #   Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=119
  #
  #   Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
  #       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
  #   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
  #       Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 31ms, Average = 28ms
  #
--- Do stuff
```

Comment: I didn't know there was an OutputDataReceived event I could have listened on. This would have made my script way easier had I designed it around this paradigm. I'll remember this in the future.