# Is it possible to have -RedirectStandardOutput in Start-Process but still display it in the console?

Tags: powershell, tee, start-process, redirectstandardoutput

My problem is that I want to `Start-Process` a powershell file, `execute.ps1`, that would execute several sql commands then log the outputs in a text file. So far, all the other approaches like `start-transcript` or `*>>` just writes the console outputs but not the sql PRINTS. The only thing currently working is `-RedirectStandardOutput`.

`Start-Process powershell "& .\execute.ps1 -dbserver $server -databasename $database -client $client" -RedirectStandardOutput ".\output\$client.txt`

However, when I use this, it redirects everything to the txt file leaving the powershell console blank.

Is it possible to display it both in the console and the txt file?

Comment: `Start-Process ...; Get-Content ".\output\$client.txt" -Wait`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Wouldnt this show on the script that has the Start-Process command and not on the actual script? Also, wouldnt this remove the font colors?

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to stream the output back to the launching host. Can you show us the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Im sorry, I cant since they are confidential. But basically, it deploys a dacpac that has sql scripts with PRINTS. these PRINTS show normally in the powershell console, but would only show into my log file if I used -RedirectStandardOut. But again, that makes the consoles blank.

Comment: @Pa3k.m No matter what you will lose the original output color emitted by the program, if you need to redirect, store to a variable, output while also writing to a file, etc. At least, there are no built-in ways I know of to do so, or else I imagine `Tee-Object` and `Write-Host` would incorporate this in some fashion. Color information is not passed down the pipeline. I would love to be proven wrong here, however.

Comment: @Pa3k.m Note that `Write-Host` *does* allow you to set `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor`, although you would have to set this, there is no way for it to introspect what the original color was. Additionally, `Write-Host` doesn't get written to the success stream, and so cannot be passed down the pipeline for further processing within the same PowerShell session.

Answer (score 2):

No. However...

#### Using `ForEach-Object` to write output to console and append to a file

You may be able to work around it with a `Foreach-Object` loop if the sole reason you are redirecting output is to drop it in a file for later processing. However, you won't be able to use `Start-Process` to control the location of the output:

> **Note:** `$_.Trim()` is required to prevent additional newlines in Windows PowerShell 5.1 from being output to the file. `.Trim()` should not be needed as of at least 7.2.3.
>
> You could also opt for `Tee-Object` to replace the two-line block with a one-line block, however, you lose control over the encoding as `Tee-Object` does not allow you to set this for its output file.

```
# Example command: ping
ping google.com | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Trim() | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -Append .\testping.txt
  $_
}
```

If you *need* to use `Start-Process` however, for example:

- You need to run a GUI application and block until it completes
- You are launching an elevated process
- You are launching a process as another user

Then you are out of luck. `Start-Process` only allows you to redirect input and output streams from and to files, respectively.

---

#### Using `[Process]::Start` to display output as the program runs while redirecting

There is a solution to be had if you call [`[Process]::Start(StartInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0) yourself, but this is going to be the most advanced solution, and have the most code involved. But, if you find that you need `Start-Process` *and also* want the output to be displayed as the program runs, and not just once the child process ends, I would invite you to take a look at [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69652895/584676). The question is ultimately looking to process lines of output asynchronously using process object started with `[Process]::Start(StartInfo)`.

Rather than reiterate those solutions here, the answers I would direct you to focus on are [@mklement0's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653474/584676) and [@HAL9256's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670803/584676), although [@Cpt.Whale's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653789/584676) answer using `Start-Job` and
`Receive-Job` might work for your needs as well if you don't need to process each line as they are written. In your case, "processing the output asynchronously" just means you want to output the line of output to the Success stream, then append the line to your output file (as shown in the earlier `ForEach-Object` loop example).

---

#### If displaying the output can wait until the child process completes

If you don't care that the program emits its output until after it finishes running, you can look at my [synchronous implementation in my other question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69652895/584676) which should simplify things a bit.

Even more simply, use `Start-Process -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput FILE` and run
`Get-Content` against the `RedirectStandardOutput` file path you chose once the process is done executing.

---

#### Making errors output a different color

Regardless of how you launch the process and perform STDOUT/STDERR redirection, if you want the *error* information to be in a different color, just read from the error text and use `Write-Host` to change the color:

```
# $errorStream will need to first be populated from [Process].StandardError
# or Get-Content $pathToStandardErrorFile, depending on the technique used
$errorStream | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
```

Keep in mind that this in no way retains the original color information. However, it will write anything that was written to STDERR in Red (or any other color you choose). That said, *also keep in mind* that not all programs use STDERR for error information. Some use STDOUT to emit error information (perhaps erroneously), and others may use STDERR for other information such as verbose, debug, or trace output.

There isn't a one-size-fits-all workaround here, since programs are not required to (and may have good reason not to in some cases) adhere to standards and best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! Unfortunately, I do need start-process so the first option wont work. The very last option wont work either as Get-Content would ultimately remove the red font for errors which is the main reason I wanted this, to basically be able to see errors quickly when hundreds of powershell windows are open.

Comment: As for the rest of your answers, it might take me time to fully understand what you are suggesting here

Also, is the link for your synchronous implementation correct? It seems to point to the same question you had for the one above

Comment: I mentioned it in another comment on the question but you are going to lose color information if you need to redirect the output, or even assign it to a variable without using `Start-Process`. However, you can redirect STDERR just like you can redirect STDOUT, so whether you use the `Process` class or `Start-Process`, when you read the property/file with the STDERR information just use `Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red` to display STDERR in red.

Comment: I dont mind losing color information to the redirected outputs as long as the outputs in the original console has it.

Comment: Just remember that `Write-Host` writes to the information stream, which is not able to be passed down the pipeline or be otherwise assigned. It can be processed from a parent process which calls your script, but not within the same PowerShell session once it's written to the console.

Comment: @Pa3k.m That's the problem... you will lose the color information with *any* intermediate step in trying to process the output at all, even to first write to a file and then to the console. But the write-host solution may work for your needs since you just want error output in a different color. But keep in mind that not all programs use STDERR for error information.

Comment: @Pa3k.m I updated my answer with the specific workaround I was talking about in the comments, using `Write-Host -ForegroundColor` to control the STDERR output color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244779/discussion-between-pa3k-m-and-bender-the-greatest).